# Scaling the legend on amCharts

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

All of my charts scale perfectly when I resize a window, however I'm using a legend on a pie chart and it doesn't scale, only the piechart resizes.

It possible to get the legend to adjust as well?

Answer (score 0):

The PieChart has some problems with automatic legend sizing, the pie may become too small when you have many items in the legend.

The solution is to make a separate container for the legend:

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/

In this way you can have a scrollable legend container with as many items you want that doesn't interfere with the chart container.

You could also try moving the legend on the sides, better than the standard footer position, but it works only if you don't have too many items.